# divs positioning in parent div keeping aspect ratio by height

Tags: css

I have one `div` container and want to position 10 `divs` inside it.

```
------------
||---||---||    <- container
|| 1 || 2 ||
||---||---||
||---||---||
|| 3 || 4 ||
||---||---||
||---||---||
|| 5 || 6 ||
||---||---||
||---||---||
|| 7 || 8 ||
||---||---||
||---||---||
|| 9 || 10||
||---||---||
------------
```

I want these `divs` to be squares, always in 2 columns and I want them to be 20% of the parent height. Parent `div` must not be allowed to change its `width` less than the sum of the 2 inner `divs` and is ok to be extended (inner `divs` must be attached to the left)

I'm seeking solution with css.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: When is your homework due?

Comment: If you are looking for a css solution, then the least you could do is post the html code you want it to affect..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calc();` option in css.

For example; if your wrapper div is `100%` in height, it is `100vh`. Than you can use this to set inner divs width and height:

```
.innerdiv {
    height: 20vh;
    width: 20vh;
}
```

Read about it here: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Support is decent: http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Comment: If you found this helpful, please accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: This actually solves my problem. Couldn't find this, although it was before my eyes. I tried several ways to resize this zone properly with viewports with no success. And all this is beside my other tries with percentages, bootstrap, etc. My question was generic as It had to be. Which html structure to present in the question as I have at least 10 prototypes?

Comment: This is an awesome way to solve this. If you need more help on this, let me know.